# Django: passing AJAX POST data to Django yields MultiValueDictKeyError even though key exists

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, post

My Ajax call has in it the data:

```
data: { hint: {'asdf':4} },
```

I feel like I should be able to access this object with

```
request.POST['hint'] # and possibly request.POST['hint']['asdf'] to get 4
```

but this error comes in the way. I look at

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /post_url/
"'hint'"
```

When I print the post data I get strangely misformed dictionary:

```
<QueryDict: {u'hint[asdf]': [u'4']}>
```

How am I supposed to correctly pass the data, so I that I retain the same structure in Python and use it the same way I did in JS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, in your `$.ajax` call, instead of directly putting all of your POST data into the `data` attribute, add it into another attribute with a name like `json_data`. For example:

```
data: { hint: {'asdf':4} },
```

should become:

```
data: { json_data: { hint: {'asdf':4} } },
```

Now, the `json_data` should be converted into a plain string using `JSON.stringify`:

```
data: { json_data: JSON.stringify({ hint: {'asdf':4} }) },
```

This will pass the data as a string into Django that can be retrieved by:

```
data_string = request.POST.get('json_data')
```

which can be converted to a dict-like object (assuming `json` is imported with `import json` at the top):

```
data_dict = json.loads(data_string)
```

Or, without the intermediate `data_string`:

```
data_dict = json.loads(request.POST.get('json_data'))
print data_dict['hint']['asdf'] # Should print 4
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thanx!

Comment: django makes the life very hard when the subject is JSON with ajax