# Ajax not firing after I added a GeoJson 'data'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have an HTML page where a button click will fire an ajax function `showDetail()`:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" onclick="showDetail({{ test.id }});">
<strong>{{ test.test_name }}</strong></a>
```

The ajax function works well if it's like this on its own:

```
function showDetail(id){
    $.ajax({
    url : "/test/" + id,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
        map.removeLayer(tests);
        $('#pane-content-edit').html(data);
        $('.tests_display').animate({right:0});
    }
});
}
```

I would like to modify it having the current HTML page containing a Geojson. And I'd like to pass it to my ajax to pass it to the url my ajax is pointing at. So I did this:

```
function showDetail(id){
    $.ajax({
    url : "/test/" + id,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {'tests_geojson' : {{ tests_geojson | safe}}},
    success: function(data){
        map.removeLayer(tests);
        $('#pane-content-edit').html(data);
        $('.tests_display').animate({right:0});
    }
});
}
```

After adding that, it would not fire. I tried opening up the web console, nothing is happening. Can someone help? or tell me how to debug this?

Thank you!

Edit:
Additional info  - Django Framework templating

Contents of `test_geojson` showing on Leaflet map so it's most likely validated: Big geojson feature but would look generally like so:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(geojsonFeature));



{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        { "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
          "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
          },
        { "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
              ]
            },
          "properties": {
            "prop0": "value0",
            "prop1": 0.0
            }
         }
         ]
       }
```

> Edit: Temporary Solution

This looks like on the right direction. [Serializing the JSON data to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594823/django-passing-ajax-post-data-to-django-yields-multivaluedictkeyerror-even-thou), adding `csrf`, then modify things at `views.py`. However an error occurs, saying that it has exceeded Data Upload Max Memory Size so I had to set `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = None` which is a security no-no. If someone has a better workaround it'll be helpful!

```
var geojsonFeature = {{tests_geojson|safe}};
function showDetail(id){
    $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        },
    url : "/test/" + id,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'tests_geojson' : JSON.stringify(geojsonFeature)},
    success: function(data){
        map.removeLayer(tests);
        $('#pane-content-edit').html(data);
        $('.tests_display').animate({right:0});
    }
});
}
```

Comment: It is probably unable to serialize it. Can you add content of `tests_geojson`.

Comment: are you using a framework (angular?) for these placeholders (`{{ tests_geojson | safe}}`) to be replaced? is the function `showDetail` in a template?

Comment: @BrahmaDev I'll edit.

Comment: If it's angular then you can't use {{ var }} in javascript. It's only allowd in html templates. Try to replace {{ tests_geojson | safe}} with some value

Comment: @Kaddath Oh yeah I forgot to mention its django templating

Comment: You can use the browser network monitor to debug. When I replace {{ tests_geojson | safe}} with a constant value like 123 then it works for me.

Comment: After I removed the django templates it works. So I think the error is somewhere else. https://plnkr.co/edit/i4fjA2hbQbtaSz0Nbo2Y

Comment: seems like it... If no one can explain why maybe I'll really have to find another way to retrieve it. :(